# How to archive uiview all property in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift

```
enum TetrisItemEnum {

    case S
    case Z
    case L
    case J
    case I
    case O
    case T

    var rowcol:[(row:Int,col:Int)] {
        switch self {
        case .S: return [(1,0),(2,0),(0,1),(1,1)]
        case .Z: return [(0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(2,1)]
        case .L: return [(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,2)]
        case .J: return [(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(0,2)]
        case .I: return [(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3)]
        case .O: return [(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)]
        case .T: return [(0,0),(1,0),(2,0),(1,1)]
        default:
            return []
        }

    }
    var backgroundSize:(row:Int, col:Int) {
        switch self {
        case .S: return (3,2)
        case .Z: return (3,2)
        case .L: return (2,3)
        case .J: return (2,3)
        case .I: return (1,4)
        case .O: return (2,2)
        case .T: return (3,2)
        default:
            return (0,0)
        }
    }
    var color:UIColor {
        switch self {
        case .S: return UIColor.init(hexString: "#FD9E20FF")!
        case .Z: return UIColor.init(hexString: "#FECE30FF")!
        case .L: return UIColor.init(hexString: "#56C2F0FF")!
        case .J: return UIColor.init(hexString: "#28C35BFF")!
        case .I: return UIColor.init(hexString: "#FA6464FF")!
        case .O: return UIColor.init(hexString: "#22BFADFF")!
        case .T: return UIColor.init(hexString: "#FC80C3FF")!
        default:
            return .white
        }
    }

    static let allValues = [S, Z, L, J, I, O, T]
}

class TetrisItemView:UIView {

    var shape:TetrisItemEnum!

    static func makeTetrisItem(shape:TetrisItemEnum) -> TetrisItemView {
        let rspace:CGFloat = Global.rspace
        let cspace:CGFloat = Global.cspace
        let width:CGFloat = Global.width
        let height:CGFloat = Global.height

        let bgrect = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: width*CGFloat(shape.backgroundSize.row), height: height*CGFloat(shape.backgroundSize.col))
        let bgview = TetrisItemView.init(frame: bgrect)
        bgview.shape = shape
        for (i,j) in shape.rowcol  {
            let rect = CGRect.init(x: width*CGFloat(i)+rspace*(CGFloat(i)-1), y: height*CGFloat(j)+cspace*(CGFloat(j)-1), width: width, height: height);
            let view = UIView.init(frame: rect)
            view.backgroundColor = shape.color
            bgview.addSubview(view)
        }

        return bgview
    }

    func clone() -> TetrisItemView {
        let view = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self))! as! TetrisItemView

        return view
    }

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        for view in self.subviews {
            if point.x > view.frame.minX && point.x < view.frame.maxX
                && point.y > view.frame.minY && point.y < view.frame.maxY {
                return view
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}


//use
let S = TetrisItemView.makeTetrisItem(shape: shape)
let L = S.clone()
print(L.shape)
```

When I clone a uiview it was copyed rightly.
But the shape property is nil.
How do I clone all property make shape save rightly. It is in swift3.1

What is wrong with my code.

Cloud you tell me how do make it work? Thank you.

Comment: in line `let S = TetrisItemView.makeTetrisItem(shape: shape)` I don't see where and how you create `shape`, can you print it before you add it to `makeTetrisItem`?

Comment: Code is at TetrisItemView calss static func makeTetrisItem. you should scroll it to see.